# Answering multiple command line prompts to GitHub username/password

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu, command-prompt

I'm asking this because answers to similar questions have given me answers that do not work, and it may have something to do with the specifics.  I am adopting GitHub's new authentication procedure, which prompts you first for your username and then for your authentication token.  So for instance, accessing a private repository you start with:

> git clone https://userName@github.com/userName/repo.git

And then get prompted.

I've tried the following to answer the two prompts based on Stack answers, but none have worked:

> (echo userName && echo token) | git clone https://userName@github.com/userName/repo.git

And:

> echo userName > in.txt
> echo token >> in.txt
> git clone https://userName@github.com/userName/repo.git < in.txt

And:

> printf 'userName\ntoken\n' | git clone https://userName@github.com/userName/repo.git

None have worked.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm using a server running Ubuntu 18.04.5, happy to explain anything else.  Inputting the token is hard!

**Answer:** I used the instructions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) to use ssh.

And then the git clone command is written as follows:

> git clone ssh://git@github.com/userName/repo.git

Comment: Consider using SSH for automation. If this is for cloning onto a server for deployment, you can create per-repo deploy keys in github.

Comment: You need to use tools like [tag:expect] if it's required to run git in an interactive way. It's because a well implemented program would avoid reading passwords from *stdin* (for security reasons), instead it reads password directly from the tty.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/773455 (see the least-popular "cache" answer if you don't want to use gnome-keyring)

Comment: As @jordanm suggested, you can setup SSH authentication. Then you won't need to enter your password every time or use an insecure way to automate authentication. Check [Github SSH documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) for more into.

Comment: Ultimately ended up using ssh, thanks to @jordanm

Answer (score 1):

> Ultimately ended up using ssh,

That is one way.

But on Linux, do install:

- [Microsoft Git-Credential-Manager-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/#linux)
- Add a [credential store](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/linuxcredstores.md)

That way, you won't have to enter or pipe your credentials to any git clone/push/pull command.